# The text ends before the page does. Read the description

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have been making CSS changes in my blog and I have encountered this error. The text in the post dont go till the end. 
Please see this image- http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-bcAhPCuomvM/UUmYh0GX5kI/AAAAAAAADFE/LjxL60gmtqc/s1600/error+css.png

I need to make the text go further till the end of the page!!
My blog address is www.epiblog.in

The worst part of my problem is, I dont know what changes had i exactly made..

Comment: You need to post your code and CSS before we can really help you. Also telling us what 'CSS changes' you have been making might help.

Comment: Debugging images is hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My super-amazing image debugging skills tell me that you've got a fixed width of 755px on the `#main-wrapper`. Adjust and the space will be gone (you'll need to adjust the widths of the other sections too).

**Jokes aside, I found his blog by navigating to his profile, used Chrome Dev tools and found the fixed width on `#main-wrapper`**

Here's his blog: http://www.epiblog.in/2013/03/best-skullcandy-sound-systems-earphones.html

Comment: "this space" looks bad indeed, i understand @ReshamPanth wants to fix it asap according to his comics.

Comment: i tried changing the values in #main-wrapper. It just increases the width of the page. The text dont go any further..

Comment: @ReshamPanth Try increasing the width on `.post_wrapper2`

Comment: @ReshamPanth No problems. If this was the answer please click the tick next to it to mark it as correct. Welcome to SO!